# for loop string to integer

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I've been struggling to find a way to convert a string to an integer from a .txt file using MATLAB.

Here is an example of what my file looks like:

```
genes    total_muts
A2M      1
AARS     4
AASS     6
ABCA1    105
ABCA3    71
ABCA4    563
```

And here is the script that I am using:

```
genes_disease = dataset('file', 'genes_totalshuffle.txt', 'Delimiter', '\t');
gene = genes_disease.genes
total_muts = genes_disease.total_muts
a = 0

fileID = fopen('genes_totalshuffled.txt', 'w')
for k = 1:length(genes_disease)
    total_muts1 = total_muts(k);
    num_total_muts = str2num(total_muts1)       
    r = randi([a num_total_muts],1);
    fprint(fileID, '%4f %4f\n', num_total_muts, r)
end
fclose(fileID)
```

When I run this script, I get an error that informs me that the size input of `randn` needs to be numeric. I think my problem lies with the `totalmuts` variable. This variable prints strings instead of integers. I thought I could use `str2num()`, but I can't seem to get that to work appropriately. Any suggestions?

*Edited: included how I tried to use `str2num`. Also, I'm trying to generate a randomly generated number between 0 and the value listed in my file.

Comment: There are several things in your question which I don't get. Just to the point: if your variable `var` equals the string `'1'` (does it??), then you can turn it into an integer with `num2str(var)`.

Comment: Also the assignment (k:k) is useless, just use (k).

Comment: "I thought I could use `str2num()`, but I can't seem to get that to work appropriately" - please add the code of how you tried to use this.

Comment: And the two filenames don't match... or is that intentional? One is input and the other's input?

Comment: @Dan oh I missed that. I'm guessing the data also contains the first column's string input.

Comment: @Dan I intentionally edited "Matlab" to "MATLAB" since that is the official product name.

Comment: `rand([0 1],1)` is giving your error when I run your code. What do you want this line to do?

Comment: Well, yea. You are trying to create a `[0 x a x 1]` 3D matrix, where `a` is whatever the loop spits out. You cannot have a zero-sized dimension in your matrix, what is your intention with this?

Comment: Can't be that, `rand([1 1],1)` has a similar issue.

Comment: I've edited my post. I'm trying to generate a random number between 0 and number listed in my file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`randi`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to generate a number between `0` and `totalmuts` with

```
r = randi([0 totalmuts]);
```

I had to change the input data to be a CSV

```
genes,total_muts
A2M,1
AARS,4
AASS,6
ABCA1,105
ABCA3,71
ABCA4,563
```

Then the code to

```
genes_disease = dataset('file', 'genes_totalshuffle.txt', 'Delimiter', ',');
gene = genes_disease.genes
total_muts = genes_disease.total_muts
a = 0

fileID = fopen('genes_totalshuffled.txt', 'w')
for k = 1:length(genes_disease)
    totalmuts = total_muts(k);
    genename = gene(k);
    r = randi([a totalmuts]);
    fprintf(fileID, '%4f %4f\n', totalmuts, r) % consider %d or %3d
end
fclose(fileID)
```

And it worked fine for me, outputting

```
1.000000 1.000000
4.000000 0.000000
6.000000 3.000000
105.000000 47.000000
71.000000 46.000000
563.000000 400.000000
```

Comment: `rand(1)` is superfluous in this case.  Just call `rand` by itself.  However, the OP wants an **integer**, so use `randi` instead.

Comment: Ah the original syntax makes sense then. `randi([0 totalmuts],1)`

Comment: @Steve, Yes!! However, when I try to use this I get an error: 'size and inputs must be numeric'. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: My version of MATLAB gives `total_muts` as a vector of numbers. I did mess around with it a bit though. I couldn't get `\t` as a separator, and had to change it to `','` and change your data file to have commas, but it worked then

Comment: @Steve I'll convert my file to CSV and then I'll let you know if it worked. Thank you! :)

Comment: I managed to get it working with tabs: had to edit `genes_totalshuffle.txt` with something other than MATLAB, since I had "Tab key inserts spaces" ticked in Preferences>Editor/Debugger/Tab